# For any natural numbers $a,b,c$, prove the associativity property $(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$.

Tags: real-analysis, induction, peano-axioms, associativity

For any natural numbers $a,b,c$, we have $(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

We shall prove it by induction on $c$. For $c = 0$, we have that $(a + b) + 0 = a + b$ and $a + (b + 0) = a + b$.  Let us assume that $(a + b) + c = a + (b + c)$ for a natural number $c$ and prove the relation holds for $c\texttt{++}$. Indeed, one has
\begin{align*}
(a + b) + c\texttt{+}\texttt{+} = ((a + b) + c)\texttt{+}\texttt{+} = (a + (b + c))\texttt{+}\texttt{+} = a + (b + c)\texttt{+}\texttt{+} = a + (b + c\texttt{+}\texttt{+})
\end{align*}

Can someone check if I am reasoning rightly?

Comment: The idea is good.  Without seeing the definition you have for addition we cannot check if you have used if properly.  It looks like you have $a+b++=(a+b)++$ as your axiom.

Comment: The definition of addition is given by $(n\texttt{+}\texttt{+}) + m = (n + m)\texttt{+}\texttt{+}$. However, it has already been proven that $n + (m\texttt{+}\texttt{+}) = (n +m)\texttt{+}\texttt{+}$.

Comment: Then you are in good shape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof by induction :

$\displaystyle (a + b) + c^+$ $\hspace{0.25in}$

$=\displaystyle((a + b) + c)^+$$\hspace{0.195in}$Definition of Addition in Minimal Infinite Successor Set

$=\displaystyle (a + (b + c))^+$$\hspace{0.195in}$Induction Hypothesis

$=\displaystyle a + ((b + c)^+)$$\hspace{0.25in}$Definition of Addition in Minimal Infinite Successor Set

$=\displaystyle a + (b + c^+)$$\hspace{0.32in}$Definition of Addition in Minimal Infinite Successor Set

So $\ P (c) \implies P (c^+)$  and the result follows by the Principle of Mathematical Induction.